# How to download document from google drive in React js?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I am working on an ed tech platform. In this scenario a student can see and download his/her hall ticket from front end. The hall ticket is stored in the google drive. And the URL is stored in the DB. We get the URL, we show preview the file in the frontend,Easy. But can you help me with the download functionality?

Dialogue Component to show the hall ticket

```
<DialogAtom
        isOpen={openHallTicket}
        maxWidth="lg"
        customClass={classes.imageModal}
        closeOnBlur={() => setopenHallTicket(false)}
        content={(
          <DialogContent
            p={0}
          >
            <Grid container className={classes.imageSec}>
              <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.rightIcons} display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="flex-end">
                <ThemeProvider theme={toolTipTheme}>
                  <Tooltip title={t('PRINT')}>
                    <IconButton onClick={handlePrintHallTicket}>
                      <PrintIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                  <Tooltip title={t('DOWNLOAD')}>
                    <IconButton className={classes.downloadIcon} onClick={(e) => download()}>
                      {/* <a
                        href={HallTicketImage}
                        download
                      > */}
                        <FileDownloadOutlinedIcon />
                      {/* </a> */}
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                  <Tooltip title={t('CLOSE')}>
                    <IconButton
                      className={classes.emailIcon}
                      onClick={() => setopenHallTicket(false)}
                    >
                      <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                </ThemeProvider>
              </Grid>
              {/* <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<uniqueId>/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe> */}
              <CardMedia
                ref={componentRefHallTicket}
                component="iframe"
                sx={{height : '50rem'}}
                // className={classes.profileImg}
                // component="img"
                // image={HallTicketImage}
                // image={() => {<iframe src='https://drive.google.com/file/d/<uniqueId>/view'/>}}
                // image={<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<uniqueId>/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>}
                image='https://drive.google.com/file/d/<uniqueId>/preview'
                // image='https://drive.google.com/file/d/<uniqueId>/view'
                alt="certificate"
              />
            </Grid>
          </DialogContent>
```

This will produces something like this
[image]

And for download this -->

```
  const download = (e) => {
    fetch('https://drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=<uniqueId>&export=download', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        authorization: <uniqueAuth>
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        response.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer]));
          const link = document.createElement('FileDownloadOutlinedIcon');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', 'image.png'); // or any other extension
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        });
      });
  };
  // const downloadFile = () => {
  //   fetch("https://drive.google.com/file/d/<uniqueId>/preview")
  //     .then((response) => response.blob())
  //     .then((blob) => {
  //       const link = document.createElement('a');
  //       link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  //       link.download = resourceName;
  //       link.click();
  //     });
  // };
```

This is the download Button
[image]

Please Help me

Comment: What mimeType of the file is?

Comment: mimeType is pdf

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Showing CORS error`, unfortunately, when I tested my script, no error occurs. I think that the reason for the no error is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, it seems that your question was resolved. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful. So, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 1):

This is working

```
onClick={(e) => {window.open("https://drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=<fileId>&export=download", "_blank");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is the simplest one really. Just use  tag with dynamic "href" url